# What is the relationship between polymorphism's rank and (im)predicativity?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, programming-languages, parametric-polymorphism, impredicativetypes

What is the relationship between polymorphism's rank and (im)predicativity?

Can rank-1 polymorphism be either predicative or impredicative?

Can rank-k polymorphism with *`k > 1`* be either predicative or impredicative?

My confusions come from:

Why does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism mention predicativity under rank-1 polymorphism? (Seems to me rank-1 implies predicativity)

> **Rank-1 (prenex) polymorphism**
>
> In a prenex polymorphic system, **type variables may not be instantiated with polymorphic types**.[4] This is very similar to what is called "ML-style" or
>   "Let-polymorphism" (technically ML's Let-polymorphism has a few other
>   syntactic restrictions). This restriction makes the distinction
>   between polymorphic and non-polymorphic types very important; thus in
>   predicative systems polymorphic types are sometimes referred to as
>   type schemas to distinguish them from ordinary (monomorphic) types,
>   which are sometimes called monotypes. A consequence is that **all
>   types can be written in a form that places all quantifiers at the
>   outermost (prenex) position**. For example, consider the append
>   function described above, which has type
>
> ```
> forall a. [a] × [a] -> [a]
> ```
>
> In order to apply this function to a pair of lists, a type must be
>   substituted for the variable `a` in the type of the function such that
>   the type of the arguments matches up with the resulting function type.
>
> In an impredicative system, the type being substituted may be any type
>   whatsoever, including a type that is itself polymorphic; thus append
>   can be applied to pairs of lists with elements of any type—even to
>   lists of polymorphic functions such as append itself. Polymorphism in
>   the language ML is predicative.<sup>[citation needed]</sup> This is because
>   predicativity, together with other restrictions, makes the type system
>   simple enough that full type inference is always possible.
>
> As a practical example, OCaml (a descendant or dialect of ML) performs
>   type inference and supports impredicative polymorphism, but in some
>   cases when impredicative polymorphism is used, the system's type
>   inference is incomplete unless some explicit type annotations are
>   provided by the programmer.
>
> ...
>
> **Predicative polymorphism**
>
> In a predicative parametric polymorphic system, a type `τ` containing
>   **a type variable `α` may not be used in such a way that `α` is
>   instantiated to a polymorphic type**. Predicative type theories include
>   Martin-Löf Type Theory and NuPRL.

https://wiki.haskell.org/Impredicative_types :

> Impredicative types are an advanced form of polymorphism, to be
>   contrasted with rank-N types.
>
> Standard Haskell allows polymorphic types via the use of type
>   variables, which are understood to be universally quantified: `id :: a -> a` means "for all types `a`, `id` can take an argument and return a result of that type". All universal quantifiers ("for all"s) must
>   appear at the beginning of a type.
>
> Higher-rank polymorphism (e.g. rank-N types) allows universal
>   quantifiers to appear inside function types as well. It turns out that
>   appearing to the right of function arrows is not interesting: `Int -> forall a. a -> [a]` is actually the same as `forall a. Int -> a -> [a]`.
>
> However, higher-rank polymorphism allows quantifiers to the left of
>   function arrows, too, and `(forall a. [a] -> Int) -> Int` really is
>   different from `forall a. ([a] -> Int) -> Int`.
>
> Impredicative types take this idea to its natural conclusion:
>   universal quantifiers are allowed anywhere in a type, even inside
>   normal datatypes like lists or `Maybe`.

Thanks.

Comment: By the way, in the future, you can save yourself some heartache (and me a few seconds of effort) by explicitly linking questions you have already read which do not answer your question, and explaining why they aren't answers. (This is also [officially recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so this is not just a sour grapes request.)

Answer (score 9):

> Can rank-1 polymorphism be either predicative or impredicative?

No, rank-1 polymorphism is always predicative, because any `forall` quantifiers do not appear as arguments to type constructors, that is, quantifiers are “prenex”.

> Can rank-k polymorphism with k > 1 be either predicative or impredicative?

Higher-rank polymorphism is always impredicative; the `RankNTypes` extension enables impredicative polymorphism *only* for the `(->)` constructor, that is, given a type `a -> b`, `a` or `b` may be instantiated with a type containing `forall`s. We typically refer to such types as higher-rank only when `a` contains `forall`s, because (except for `TypeApplications`) `X -> forall t. Y` is equivalent to `forall t. X -> Y`.

General impredicative polymorphism (with the broken `ImpredicativeTypes` extension) is not supported. For example, you can’t write `Maybe (forall a. [a] -> [a])`. This is essentially because it’s difficult to automatically determine when to generalise and when to instantiate that quantifier. Fortunately, you can make this explicit using a `newtype` wrapper to “hide” the impredicativity, or rather, make it clear to the compiler what you want to do about quantifiers, e.g.:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

newtype ListTransform = ListTransform { unLT :: forall a. [a] -> [a] }

f :: Maybe ListTransform -> [Int] -> [Char] -> ([Int], [Char])
f Nothing is cs = (is, cs)
f (Just (ListTransform t)) is cs = (t is, t cs)
-- or: f (Just lt) is cs = (unLT lt is, unLT lt cs)
```